# How do I close the ssh-agent.exe for Git?

Tags: git, git-for-windows

I want to uninstall Git. But when I try to I get this message:

> The following applications use files that need to be removed. Please close them
>
> ssh-agent (PID 8112, closing is required)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your case, you could call this from the command line:

```
taskkill /pid 8112
```

For further information, see the [documentation on taskkill](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx).

Comment: Sometimes you will need the `/F` flag, i.e. `taskkill /pid 8112 /F`

Comment: `8112` being an example? Perhaps make that more clear in your answer? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34637393/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 8):

Just go to [Task Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Manager_(Windows)) and locate the process with the name which is mentioned and just select that process and click the <kbd>End process</kbd> button.

Comment: As of Windows 10 the easiest way to find the task is under the "Details" tab in Task Manager.