# Git - How to Remove SSH Key on Windows 10

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I have about 5 SSH keys on my computer, and I've added 2 SSH keys by using `ssh-add` command. When listing all SSH keys, I can use `ssh-add -l` command

[image]

How can I delete a single or all SSH key that I just added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25465155/6309) `ssh-add -D` to delete all your *manually* added keys.

The other option would be to [kill the `ssh-agent` process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34637064/6309), restart it and add only the one you want to keep.

Comment: does this remove the known host that was added as well?

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS No, to my knowledge it does not.